# devise rails 6 under reverse proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

With rails 6.0.3.2  and devise 4.7.2

it is impossible to create a session with devise when the site is behind a reverse proxy

the app is accessed and connexion is ok (with passenger on http with nginx) when accessed with http protocol

when the app is accessed with https with apache2 as reverse proxy and no https in the VPN
the site is ok but it is impossible to connect with devise

the exact same (apache2 nginx passenger) setup worked ok with rails 4.2.8  and devise 4.4.3

Answer (score 1):

need this
in apache virtual host conf

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

Comment: remember to enable `mod_headers` in apache or you'll get
`Invalid command 'RequestHeader', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`